# WPF :: How can I colorize/format HTML?

Tags: html, wpf, richtextbox, code-formatting

I have a `RichTextBox` that is an HTML WYSIWYG editor that saves to HTML; requirements for the project also dictate that we provide an HTML source code editor.

What is a good way to go about this?  My idea is to load the HTML text directly into a `RichTextBox`, but I can't figure out a good way to format the text - both the layout and colorizing like the HTML text editor in Visual Studio.

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have an HTML editor, which can highlight the syntax, you should use [AvalonEdit](http://avalonedit.net/). It is a powerful WPF-based text editor control.

You can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor) a very good tutorial.

Moreover you can show the resulting HTML by using a second control (for example a [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: AvalonEdit looks like a great option - and I don't have to reinvent the wheel.  Thanks!  I'm going to leave the question open for a couple of days hopefully for more options - but this looks really good.